# Swift regular expression usage

Tags: ios, regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I cannot convert this Java regular expression to swift:

```
^(?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{6,15}$
```

It basically checks for the input to have at least one uppercase, at least a number, and a minimum length of 6 characters and a maximum of 15.

The input to check against cames from a UITextField , and i have this function to check against:

```
func isValidPassword(candidate: String) -> Bool {
    let passwordRegex = "(?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z])(?=.*\\d).{6,15}"

    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passwordRegex).evaluateWithObject(candidate)
}
```

Then, in my logic i do something like this:

```
if isValidPassword(textField.text) {
    println("password is good")
} else {
    println("password is wrong")
}
```

I am always getting that wrong password log.

I even tried modifying the expression with this [Cheat Sheet](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86205/nsregularexpression-swift-tutorial) with no luck.

Anyone can spot the flaw in the regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your regex is wrong. It should be `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d).{6,15}` - note the `*` before `[a-z]` and before `[A-Z]`. It follows the same principles you already applied to the digit-group.

Still that does not fit your description because it forces a lowercase letter as well. You might want to remove the first `(?=)` group or change your expectation / description.

Comment: Worked, about the lowercase... was my mistake, i also check for at least one lowercase, i am not going to edit the question so your answer keeps making sense, might help someone running into the same issue.

Comment: You are welcome and I thank you for accepting and upvoting the answer but you although have to note that the other answer mentions another important point: adding `^` and `$`!

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is wrong, use the following regex:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d).{6,15}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wA2qW2/2)

[image]

Comment: @JuanPabloBoero , I see, I'm not soo familiar with Swift flavor of regex :), replacing `\d`with `\\d` in answer anyway :)